# Showing multiple group boxes based on the tree view selection in .Net winform

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a tree view in my win form which is having more than 10 nodes, based on selection for each node I have to show the appropriate group box in right side of the form and I have to hide other group boxes, is there any simplest way other than nested if else conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a potential solution:

Assuming you are not already using the the [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag.aspx) of the TreeNode(s) for something else, you could set that property to the corresponding GroupBox control. Then, subscribe to the [NodeMouseClick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemouseclick.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) of the TreeView control and use the Tag property of the selected node to determine which GroupBox to show. All others should be hidden.

Of course, you will want to store references to the GroupBoxes in an array. That way hiding all group boxes is as easy as:

```
foreach(var gb in arrayOfGroupBoxes)
{
    gb.Visible = false;
}
```

The implementation of the NodeMouseClick event handler might look something like:

```
void TVNodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    var activeGroupBox = e.Node.Tag as GroupBox;

    foreach(var gb in arrayOfGroupBoxes)
    {            
        gb.Visible = ReferenceEquals(activeGroupBox, gb);
    }
}
```